# Build or pack a nodejs script so that it is self-contained

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, build

I have a javascript codebase with a structure like this:

```
node_modules/
src/
   /script1
   /script2
   /script3
package.json
package.lock
.env
```

etc...

The scripts are simple utilities **that sometimes include code from each other's folders** to maximize code reuse. Even if they didn't do that, they share the same `node_modules` folder so they are entangled anyway.

I want to run something like webpack on `/script2` (but without targeting the web) so that all its unique dependencies are inlined as one massive JS script... (Or failing that, build its unique dependencies to output its own node_modules and package.json files... but that sounds way more complex).

How do I keep the current project structure but still build standalone pieces as needed, for different environments (mainly serverless functions)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can run webpack on each one of the files as an entry, and configure webpack to work with [`node`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/) target.

Comment: omg THANK YOU! I had just started reading about webpack and realised it might be the solution after all but I kept getting errors until you pointed me at the 'node' target info!